# How do I target the nodes of a child of a child that I created through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a table with JavaScript. It's located in a Div that has a name. It creates a table, which creates a tbody, which then has a number of td and tr.

I'm trying to target those td and tr with an event listener so that when I hover over them, they switch background color.

I've tried a few things, I put two in the code.

So yeah, how do I target the JavaScript created cells and make them change color on hover?

HTML

```html
<div id="padDiv">
    <!-- The JS pad goes here -->
</div>
```

Javascript #1

```
table.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "block";
})

/* The code that creates the td and tr has this in it: */

let tbl = document.createElement("table");
let table = document.getElementsByClassName("table");
padDiv.appendChild(tbl);
```

Javascript #2

```
let table = document.getElementsbyId("padDiv").childNodes[0];

table.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "block";
})
```

That last one I thought would make sense, because using...

```
padDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "block";
})
```

allowed me to color the cells like I wanted, but the whole div became black if I hovered over an area that was the div, but not occupied by a cell (margins).

So yeah, how do I target a the td and tr that are created alongside my table, considering the last thing that has a name when the page is created is padDiv?

Edit: The color needs to stay around until I hit a reset button.

Comment: If you create the rows/cells by Javascript, why not adding the event handler to each of them?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't highlight anything. I tried to give the table element a class of table, and nothing happens. It gets the class, but I can't apply anything to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to alter background color with a 'mouseenter' listener attached to every `td` element in the `tbody`.  It uses the Id of a table to dig in and find all of the relevant elements to apply the listener to.

When you want to clear the background color simply loop through your cells and set their background colors back to "initial".

```js
var table = document.getElementById("StickyHighlight");
var body = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
var cells = body[0].getElementsByTagName("td");  
 
function addHoverListener() {
  for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
      e.target.style.background = "cyan";
    });
  }
}

function reset() {
  for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){  
    cells[i].style.background = "initial";
  }
}

addHoverListener();
```

```css
thead {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

<table id="StickyHighlight">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
      <td>Col 3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Thing 1</td>
      <td>Thing 2</td>
      <td>Thing 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thing 1</td>
      <td>Thing 2</td>
      <td>Thing 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thing 1</td>
      <td>Thing 2</td>
      <td>Thing 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified I need the color to stick around.

Comment: This does it! Thanks!